# Facebook sliding like box not stable in IE 9

Tags: plugins, internet-explorer-9, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have problem with facebook plugin in [my website](http://www.fedri.com). It's showing correctly in Firefox but in IE 9 it's not showing stable. It's moving fast and can't be visible. Please open my above link in IE and have a look.

This is the code in Overall_Header.Html which is placed after the closing of Head tag.

```
     <body id="phpbb" class="section-{SCRIPT_NAME} {S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<a id="facebook_tab" href="https://www.facebook.com/fedriksa" title="Fedri on Facebook"><span><div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fedriksa" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div></span></a>
<div id="wrap">
```

And, This is my .CSS style refering to facebook_tab

```
#facebook_tab
{
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 102px;
    background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/facebook_tab.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    right:0px;
    top:200px;
    position:fixed;
}

#facebook_tab span
{
    display: none;
}

#facebook_tab:hover {
width:292px;
padding-left:32px;
}

#facebook_tab:hover span
{
    display:block;
background-color:#fff;
border:2px solid #999;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Please help me in getting rid of this. Many many thanks.